# str_ireplace to not target part of word

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

First of all my PHP knowledge is pretty bad.

I'm currently using this function to translate strings on a wordpress site:

```
 function translate_text($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Date', 'Dato', $translated);
return $translated;
}
```

My issue is that it takes all cases of date, even if the string "date" is within another word. 
This means that a button with the text "Opdater" becomes "OpDator".

How do i make it target strings that are not part of another word but only that word alone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use regular expressions, preg_match

Comment: Surely Wordpress has translation functionality built in? Why not just use that? Or are you doing something different?

Comment: Wordpress has no built in translator. Many plugins are made only in english (im danish making a danish site). translator plugins sometimes slows down the site a lot.

Thanks for the preg_match suggestions though. It's exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) and [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`)

```
preg_replace("/\bdate\b/i", "Dato", $string);
```

https://eval.in/555384

Comment: @EmilØstervig Awesome, glad I could help. The way SO works is by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/246338) that helped solved your problem to let others know what worked in the future, should they have the same issue, and to let others know you're no longer needing help with this question.

Comment: Yeah, i know that, sorry for not pressing. had to wait 5 minutes before i could check off an answer, so i totally forgot i while implementing the solution.